# Actual Focal Length of the Tamron 70-300mm f/4-5.6 lens for Sony a7iii

Tags: focal-length, tamron

I have a Sony RX10 iv and now realize that the 600mm lens is actually just 220mm.  I am looking at the Tamron 70-300mm lens for my Sony a7iii and wondering if the Tamron shoots a full 300mm.

Comment: I suspect you may be getting confused by all the marketing hype (which is understandable, it's very confusing). Is there an actual photographic issue you have with the RX10?

Comment: The RX10 is a great camera, I was just hoping to use it for wildlife photography and was disappointed at the results.  So I am wondering if the Tamron 70-300 on my a7iii would work better.

Comment: RX10 on 220mm is equivalent of 600mm on fullframe sensor. This is because of the size of sensor.

Comment: Do you know what is the equivalent mm for the Tamron would be?

Comment: OK, I've closed this as a duplicate of our canonical "crop factor" question for now. If that doesn't point you in the right direction, please edit this question to explain exactly what you'd still like help in understanding. Thanks!

Comment: Since the Sony α7III is a full frame camera, there is no crop factor to account for. On a FF camera a 300mm lens obviously gives a 300mm "equivalent (FF camera)" angle of view. On the other hand, your Sony RX10 has a much smaller sensor and the 220mm lens used on it gives an equivalent angle of view of a 600mm lens used on a FF camera.